# how to handle Joined script having null values(no data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Select t.Name, a.Questions, b.Correct,c.Attempted from Topics t 
Left Join (
SELECT  COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Questions, 
Topics.Name
FROM TestResults INNER JOIN
TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
INNER JOIN QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID 
INNER JOIN Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
WHERE TestResults.StudentID = 1
AND TestResults.ID = 46
GROUP BY Topics.Name) a 
On t.Name=a.Name
Inner Join (
SELECT COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Correct, 
Topics.Name
FROM TestResults INNER JOIN
TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
INNER JOIN QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID 
AND TestResults2.Answer = QuestionBank.Answer 
INNER JOIN Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
WHERE TestResults.StudentID = 1
AND TestResults.ID = 46
GROUP BY Topics.Name) b 
On t.Name=b.Name
Inner Join (
SELECT COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Attempted, 
Topics.Name
FROM  TestResults INNER JOIN
TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
INNER JOIN QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID 
AND TestResults2.Answer <> '\0' 
INNER JOIN Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
WHERE TestResults.StudentID = 1
AND TestResults.ID = 46
GROUP BY Topics.Name) c 
on c.Name=t.Name
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Joined script having null values means?

Comment: select statement not having data "on c.Name=t.Name" C.name doesn't have the name in the particular select statement.

Comment: Your question is still not clear

Comment: (select name )  as t
Inner Join(
SELECT    Topics.Name
) c on c.Name=t.Name 

"C" CTE table is not having name which we have joined. so it will show null.
Please go through the main script you can understand...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      t.Name, a.Questions, b.Correct,c.Attempted 
FROM        Topics t 
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT  COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Questions, 
                    Topics.Name
            FROM    TestResults 
            JOIN    TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
            JOIN    QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID 
            JOIN    Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
            WHERE   TestResults.StudentID = 1
            AND     TestResults.ID = 46
            GROUP   BY Topics.Name) a On t.Name=a.Name
LEFT JOIN       (
            SELECT  COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Correct, 
                    Topics.Name
            FROM    TestResults 
            JOIN    TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
            JOIN    QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID AND TestResults2.Answer = QuestionBank.Answer 
            JOIN    Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
            WHERE   TestResults.StudentID = 1
            AND     TestResults.ID = 46
            GROUP   BY Topics.Name) b On t.Name=b.Name
LEFT JOIN       (
            SELECT  COUNT(TestResults2.QuestionID) AS Attempted, 
                    Topics.Name
            FROM    TestResults 
            JOIN    TestResults2 ON TestResults.ID = TestResults2.TestResultID 
            JOIN    QuestionBank ON TestResults2.QuestionID = QuestionBank.ID AND TestResults2.Answer <> '\0' 
            JOIN    Topics ON QuestionBank.TopicID = Topics.ID
            WHERE   TestResults.StudentID = 1 
            AND     TestResults.ID = 46
            GROUP   BY Topics.Name) c on c.Name=t.Name
```

This is your same query, I just changed some JOINS with LEFT JOIN, Check whether you able to handle NULL values.

Comment: add this also "and topics.name in (SELECT Val FROM dbo.function(@Name,',',1))" 
If I pass values like @name = 'student1,student2' it should give only 2 student count. But it is giving all student names because we used left join for all.